Temporary suspension for violating "Be nice"? Miss Understands and expected conduct
I noticed today that Miss Understands was temporarily suspended. Based on a message in a chat room I think that may have ultimately been Rory Alsop's decision, but I am not sure.
I have no connection to Miss Understands and no particular personal interest in the suspension, but I am a frequent lurker of this board and HNQ and have seen her questions (and comments) on this and other sites. She is often brash, if not outright disrespectful. She is also open about her difficulties in judging other's tone, and frequently asks for specific examples of where she can improve.
In the spirit of that request, I am opening this question: what, in the post-mortem analysis, pushed this user over the line for a temp suspension? An example that comes to mind might be not only assuming that criticism of a question is a personal attack, but then also saying so with comments such as "this guy just doesn't like me".
I remember another user who learned not to take criticism on questions as personal criticism, so I feel that the exercise could have value.

She attacked me and posted a rude remark. Not going to give details on that.

At the very least, I have seen constant flaggable rude comments and posts on some sites from this user. Those comments and posts have been deleted though, and while privileged users can see deleted posts, only mods can see deleted comments, so most users won't know the big picture. That said, mods won't indulge this private information unless the user gives explicit permission to disclose it.

"She is often brash, if not outright disrespectful. She is also open about her difficulties in judging other's tone, and frequently asks for specific examples of where she can improve."  She's been calling other people derogatory names since at least her meta question from a bit ago and its chat

While I won't post any specific comments to avoid defeating the purpose of them having been deleted, Miss Understands has a months long history of posting nasty and obnoxious comments to everyone around them across the network. They have been suspended at least 30 or so times at this point, probably 50 or so, included quite a few on this site alone, and a network-wide suspension. 6 of those suspensions are currently active. This isn't just a problem on this site.
Basically, they persistently post low-quality questions and answers and then attack users who attempt to explain such to them.
They have been warned ad infiniteum by a variety of users, myself included, and I'd imagine many mods have also explained the problem to them in private mod messages. They refuse to listen, attack those who attempt to help them, insist that being rude is okay, insist that autism is free license and forces one to be obnoxious, insists all downvoters don't read the post they downvote or are serial downvoting against them, and makes obviously fictious claims about how the system works and claims everyone is lying when told so (ex. claiming that downvotes auto-suspended you, claiming that there a feature to vote for a users suspension, claiming that Erin Anne and I are diamond mods, etc.) They'll also then threaten to leave every so often and talk about (a likely fictious) story of living in the wilderness for years and their job, in what seems like an attempt to gain sympathy.
This user has generated something like 50+ U/U or H/B/A flags from me alone from their comments and leave a trail of suspensions and low quality posts wherever they go. This has gotten to the point that I patrol their activity page every so often to look for personal attacks, and usually find a bunch. I personally think that they are not a net positive to the sites they are contributing at, and it would appear that the mods of this site and others would agree.
I am yet to see a single good-faith request by this user for trying to improve (I'm not counting things like "what an earth is wrong with this you morons. go away. what is your purported nonsense of this perfect question could possibly be improved" or similar).
You mentioned Uhoh in your question, and I would be very happy if this situation, after their suspension expires, to turn out similarly. At this point, though, I think it is unlikely. You can't improve if you can't learn. Plenty of users, you and me included, have devoted plenty of time to trying to help Miss Understands, but at some point they need to want to improve.

First of all, [+1] from a thankful recipient of such a review myself. In my case, believe it or not, it was life-changing. Feeling like a struggling outsider my whole life, the concept of "community" was a truly new concept to me, and it took years to figure out what it meant. Understanding that this is a public space, that technical criticisms or challenges were not personal attacks was a real challenge and took time and patience, and a whole lot of explaining. I'm eternally grateful for efforts like this one.
In my case, the time was right, and as the joke goes, the lightbulb was willing to change. I was willing to go off and think about it for a few years, even though the suspension was short. Also, I wrote a bit about neurodivergence challenges here; it's indeed not a "get out of jail free" card. We have to make specific efforts to simpy not say what pops into our head at the moment, and personally take a step back when the fight-or-flight reflex kicks in (yes ASCII can look threatening to us). This could be a good opportunity for them as well.
Expected conduct
It is REALLY frustrating when community members of SE sites don't like our questions, dismiss them, criticize them, answer in a way we don't like. These things can sometimes feel like existential threats, yes.
BUT THEY ARE NOT and commenting, replying, and acting like they are is unwelcome, flagable, deletable, and ultimately, eventually suspendible. And that's for a good reason.
This is a public space, and everyone else's feelings count too!
If we don't get the answer we like, or expect, we should not complain about it. Posting an SE question is like rolling the dice: what happens next is not up to us, we can not control it, and if we try, we get in trouble!
Downvoting, not accepting answers are available options.
But comments out of frustration that deride or insult other users are just not appropriate here in this public, shared space.
Comments that go into detail about how awful things feel to us don't belong under question or answer posts in the main site. Comments like "of course I know that, I shouldn't have to say it" miss the point - in order to use this publc, shared space, we need to conform to certain guidelines and practices.
Nobody gets any wide, sweeping exceptions. We have to grow and change a bit to  learn to contribute without leaving a big mess of emotional comments or venting our personal frustrations in the main site.
